# Sequelize convert date from UTC to local

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, mariadb, sequelize.js

I have a problem with queries in sequelize.js.

In database I store model with `myDate` field which is stored in UTC. I also have a query where time period is specified:

`AND p.myDate BETWEEN :dateStart AND :dateEnd`

Using `sequelize.query`, I replace parameters with:

- `dateStart: 2018-09-11T22:00:00.000Z`
- `dateEnd: 2018-09-14T14:15:40.609Z`

and now the problem is that I see query is executing however with localTime values:

`AND p.myDate BETWEEN '2018-09-12 00:00:00' AND '2018-09-14 16:15:40'`

Why did it convert it to the local time? I was not able to find the right answer.

Comment: one of the possible way(may not be the best way) to do it to store your time in epoch format in database and whenever you need to display data  on app just use moment.format().  In this way comparison in where clause wouldn't create any issue.

Comment: @getashu1, probably yes, that would be the way to go although I have spotted strange behaviour in sequelize library and I would like to know the root cause of it.

Comment: did you try using timezone option in dialectoptions

Comment: according to http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-constructor-constructor, if it is not set then `default: '+00:00'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the time zone in which you want to read/write in the config of Sequelize like this.

```
development: {
    username: 'postgres',
    password: 'postgres',
    database: 'your_database_name',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
      useUTC: false, // for reading from database
    },
    timezone: '+05:30', // for writing to database
  },
```

Comment: It does not answer my question: why did it convert dates to local time.